# Spring cloud sleuth how to allow certain URL pattern alone to export traces to zipkin

Tags: zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

Requirement is to export traces for requests that matches url pattern to zipkin from apps. I got to know that there are options in sleuth properties to exclude traces from exporting. But my case is the opposite of it. Include traces for exporting for only specified url patterns.

I was trying to have a custom httpSampler and mentioned my logic to export the trace based on url patterns. But it did not work as expected. Any samples available on the same, would really be helpful? Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **spring.sleuth.web.skipPattern**

sample you will get here https://www.baeldung.com/tracing-services-with-zipkin

Comment: Thanks much. It works fine. Do you have any samples, where it behaves like export only the mentioned urls instead of exclude certain urls from exporting